# Linear Layout - Only RecyclerView scrolls

Tags: android, scroll, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to scroll all of the page but only `RecyclerView` scrolling in that light blue area? what can i do? here is my xml. When i try to scroll, only `RecyclerView` scrolls in its area.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/tab_user_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="11pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/tabsScrollColor"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/tab_user_name"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tabsScrollColor"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/tab_user_follower"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/tab_user_following"
            android:textColor="@color/tabsScrollColor"
            android:textSize="8pt"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/tabsScrollColor"
            android:id="@+id/tab_user_point"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/star_smooth"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tab_user_recycler_view"
        />



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:id="@+id/tab_user_fab"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/fab_transition_name"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_image"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tab_user_recycler_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/app_color"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is an image how it looks:

[image]

Comment: LinearLayout does not scroll

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling needs to be enabled by wrapping your `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`.

But if you do that, then your scroll might disrupt since you have a `RecyclerView` in a `ScrollView`.

Easiest one is your top image and text to be wrapped into a separate cell (renderer) and then add it just like any other cell in your recycler view.

Comment: Agree with Dimitar,

You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, since ListView takes care of its own scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.